# How to Pass user_id to Modal popup and display corresponding users in JSP?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I want to display the user with specific Id in the modal popup. How can send the id to modal and send it to dao file so that I can retrieve that user from database.

After sending that id to modal, I want to get the id from js and save it to a variable for furter processing.

**Javascript** -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#myinfo').click(function (e)
            {                         
                var userId = $(this).data('id');;      
                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: "memberlist.jsp", //or whatever your url is
                    data: "userId=" + userId,
                    success: function(data){      
                        $(".tables").html(data);
                    }
                });
            });

        });
```

**View, Edit & Delete Buttons** -

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-id="<%=bean.getId()%>" data-target="#myinfo" data-uid="1" class="update btn btn-info btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></button>
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-id="<%=bean.getId()%>" data-target="#myModalharsha" data-uid="2" class="update btn btn-warning btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button>
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-id="<%=bean.getId()%>"  data-target="#delete" data-uid="2" class="delete btn btn-danger btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button></td>
```

**Memberlist.jsp** -

```
<div class="table-responsive bs-example widget-shadow">
                    <h4>Member Details:</h4>
                            <input type="text" name="userId" id="userId" value=""/>

                    <table class="table table-hover"> 
                    <%
                        String id = request.getParameter("userId");
                        int userId = Integer.parseInt(id);
                        UserBean bean = UserDao.viewUser(userId);

                    %>
                            <tr> 
                                <td><b>Name:</b></td> 
                                <td><%=bean.getName() %></td>
                            </tr> 
                            <tr> 
                                <td><b>Email ID:</b></td> 
                                <td><%=bean.getEmailId() %></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr> 
                                <td>Mobile:</td>
                                <td><%=bean.getMobile() %></td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                                <td><b>Business Name:</b></td>
                                <td><%=bean.getBusinessName() %></td>
                           </tr>   
                           <tr>
                                <td><b>Address:</b></td>
                                <td><%=bean.getAddress() %></td>
                           </tr> 
                           <tr>
                                <td><b>Created:</b></td>
                                <td><%=bean.getCreated() %></td>
                           </tr> 
                           <tr>
                                <td><b>User Type:</b></td>
                                <td><%=bean.getUserType() %></td>
                           </tr> 
                           <tr>
                                <td><b>ParentType:</b></td>
                                <td><%=bean.getParentType() %></td>
                           </tr>
            </table>
            </div>
  </div>
```

Please help me -

Comment: There are basically two ways: either create a modal for each user inside your server loop (`UserBean bean : list`), or request the data from the server via AJAX/fetch() based on the clicked id.

Comment: Which one is more efficient?

Comment: The first one always dumps all user data into the doc, so in terms of traffic and RAM, the second one needs less.

Comment: Can you please give me one complete example? I never worked with AJAX and I need to implement urgently.

Comment: Assuming `user.jsp` sends user data as JSON based on `id` param: `fetch("user.jsp?id=" + user_id).then(r => r.json()).then(data => { /* put data in modal */ });`

Comment: Can you please explain in detail, one simple example would work for me?

Comment: No, sorry. This isn't a free tutoring service.

Comment: Okay, just give me the flow, please

Comment: request data from server using fetch() => insert data into modal => display modal